# Is it possible to center the content of a column based on another column for a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm currently using a grid layout, on the left column it has sections of text. On the right column, I have images. I've encountered a roadblock when making this grid work responsively, the content on the left does not line up with the images on the right because they are in two different columns.

Is it possible to have the images always centered based on where the section begins in the left grid? I've tinkered around with manually setting padding but I would prefer to find a more efficient solution if available.

https://jsfiddle.net/yhpbc9xL/2/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr;
}

.content {
  grid-column: content;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.images {
  grid-column: images;
  padding: 12%;
}

.image-one {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/600/600");
}

.image-two {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
}

.image-one,
.image-two {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12%;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="section-one">
      <h2 class="title">SECTION ONE</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="section-two">
      <h2 class="title">SECTION TWO</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

      </p>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="images">
    <div class="image-one"></div>
    <div class="image-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect `.image-one` & `image-two` in the right grid to be centered of `.section-one` and `.section-two` in the left grid.

Comment: are you open to change the HTML code?

Comment: Sure! if a grid layout is still doable

Comment: @TemaniAfif was their a solution to add the image and the content in the same container without ruining the grid flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the images and the text content are in different containers - you can try this:

- use `display: contents` for the `content` and `images` which *essentially* now are only semantic containers and their inner elements become *grid items* now (or you can drop your `content` and `images` containers in your html),
- place the `section-*` elements in `grid-column: content` and `image-*` elements in `grid-column: images`,
- add `grid-auto-flow: dense` so that the *images* column will not have any empty *grid cells*.

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [content] 1fr [images] 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* ensures no empty grid cells */
}

.content,
.images {
  display: contents;
}

.section-one,
.section-two {
  grid-column: content; /* in first column */
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.image-one {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/600/600");
}

.image-two {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
}

.image-one,
.image-two {
  grid-column: images; /* in second column */
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: white;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="section-one">
      <h2 class="title">SECTION ONE</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="section-two">
      <h2 class="title">SECTION TWO</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem
        Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="image-one"></div>
    <div class="image-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @kukkuz. Sorry it's taken me a while to get back to you.I have been trying to implement this solution all day and i've been running into roadblocks. specifically, when i use larger images fully expanded shown here, i'm having trouble with always having the image centered in the image column responsively, shown here https://jsfiddle.net/j1ha5z2v/

Comment: @Trav note that you have `background-size: 50% auto` set - which means 50% width and auto height; try `background-size: cover`?

Comment: thank you for the advice but i plan on adding white padding around the image. similar to this http://www.loisbarnyc.com/

Comment: so i believe i need to keep the background-size as 50% to show the whole image.

Comment: @Trav ohh I get it, you need 50% because of *fixed* background.

Comment: precisely, that's the why it is currently not centering the image in the image column. any suggestions?

Comment: @Trav I'm not sure if the *fixed* background taking up the 50% width is solvable... maybe if there was an option to specify min-height of a `background-image` to remove the space because of `background-size: 50% auto`, but that is also not available... I'm can't see any solution sadly

Comment: hi kukkuz i know it's been awhile but I just wanted to say your solution helped me in my final refactor. thanks for showing me this